# Amazon S3 configuration with Paperclip

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to setup paperclip to post to my Amazon s3 account.

This is there error I get back:

```
LoadError in PostsController#create
no such file to load -- aws/s3 (You may need to install the aws-s3 gem)
Rails.root: /Users/tonybeninate/Documents/Apps/PhotoBlog
```

Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
# Paperclip
has_attached_file :photo,
:storage => :s3,
:path => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
:s3_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml"),
:styles => {
  :thumb => "100x100#",
  :small => "150x150>",
  :large => "725x725" }
end
```

s3.yml (I replaced my key and secret key)

```
bucket: <%= ENV['tbhockeyboy'] || 'paperclip' %>
access_key_id: <%= ENV['my_access_key'] %>
secret_access_key: <%= ENV['my_secret_key'] %>
```

I do have the aws-s3 gem installed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get this fixed? Make sure you have

```
gem 'aws-s3'
```

in your Gemfile, and run `bundle install.`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, try using

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

in your Gemfile and `bundle install`.